# Pinescript - Plot indicator shape only above or below a certain threshold

Tags: pine-script

I would like the triangle plotshapes to only show when the yellow/blue lines cross outside of the shaded area, either above or below. So in the picture shown only the highlighted red triangle would be visible. How can I do this in pinescript 5?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Bky.jpg)

So far I have added the plotshapes but I'm unable to add conditions for them

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this upper limit defined as `upper_limit`. Then you can check if both the yellow and blue lines are above it by:

```
is_above = math.min(blue_line, yellow_line) > upper_limit
```

And then add this to your cross condition.

```
is_red_triangle = is_above and ta.crossunder(yellow_line, blue_line)
```